# OSX 10.9 auto-mount partition as a directory in my home folder

Tags: macos, mount

I've just created a partition, which I now want to have permanently mounted as a directory in my home folder. Is this possible in Mavericks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating `/etc/fstab` with

```
UUID=00F8CB3C-4760-3CE9-8F81-991EDBEF6FD7   /Users/markus/www   hfs rw,auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply create an alias in your home folder pointing to /Volumes/partition

Comment: Explanation for downvote? Did I get the question wrong?

Comment: Didn't downvote. Anyway, could you explain how to create an alias to a folder?

Comment: Hm, when I wrote that comment there was a "-1". To create an alias just right-click the folder and select "Create new alias" (or something like that) and then you got a "folder" that is always pointing to the original folder

Comment: I don't seem to have that option http://i.imgur.com/HNeOrUQ.png

Comment: Somehow when you want to create an alias of a disk you have to do it from your desktop. That's strange.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1bs30sz2ovmk0oa/screen.png
My native language isn't english so you probably won't understand the text in the screenshot :D

Comment: German is fine, I'm from Sweden ;) But I don't have that icon on my desk, probably because this is not a physical disk, but a partition.

Comment: You can change that by pressing CMD+"," (Preferences) on your desktop and then select "Disks" under "General" > "Show items on desktop" (Something like that)

Comment: Then it should display all your current mounted disks/partitions on your desktop